# DJANGO Adding a User

Tags: python, django-admin

When I am trying to add a user for in my django admin site I get this error:

**The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.last_login) was the direct cause of the following exception: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response**

I created the Super user with this command: python manage.py supersuser and was able to login with it. However, adding a user is giving me grief on proceeding with the site.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_admin/) tutorial:

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
```

And fill up the rest. Maybe try to add more details for I'm just guessing that you want to add superuser

Comment: I am able to create the superuser and log in with it. The problem I have is when I try to create another user in the site/admin console. I select to add user and enter in the username and password. When I click to save it the error above appears.

Thanks for replying.

Comment: Django Version: 1.9.3
Python Version:        3.5

Comment: try this, had the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452265/django-2-1-not-null-constraint-failed-when-creating-super-user