# Django 2.1 NOT NULL Constraint Failed When Creating Super User

Tags: django

I've been using Django for several months now without any issue but when I went to create a new project and add the super-user, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.last_login
```

All migrations have been created and applied successfully. I have destroyed and recreated the database a half dozen times to no avail. App migrations run without any problem whatsoever and this is the first time I've encountered this issue in an Django project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just realized this message was buried in the dozens of lines of error messages:

> You have 12 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
>   Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Running just `manage.py migrate` and/or `manage.py migrate appname` did not apply the required system migrations. I had to do each one individually this time for some reason.

After running each one individually I was able to create a superuser without a problem:

```
manage.py migrate admin
manage.py migrate auth
manage.py migrate contenttypes
manage.py migrate sessions
```

I've never had to do that before, however. If anyone knows a reason as to why that happened I'd love to know but I've solved the main issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too used

```
manage.py migrate admin
manage.py migrate auth
manage.py migrate contenttypes
manage.py migrate sessions
```

this helped for me
`python manage.py createsuperuser`